# Unable to redeem app codes with Configurator

Tags: ipad, apple-configurator

Configurator 1.4.2 (370). OS X 10.9

I have 20 iPads that I'm managing with Configurator.  I have purchased 20 licenses each for two apps through the Volume Purchase Program.  I have Prepared tablets with no trouble.  On the Supervise panel I assign the paid app to the devices and apply.  19/20 ipads complete successfully.

One iPad completes with an error for both apps: Unable to redeem code for "App Name". There are no codes left to redeem.

Looking at the licenses for each app it clearly says there is one remaining code available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not import the initial VPP spreadsheet into Configurator!

After receiving the initial spreadsheet from VPP, you *must* redeem one of the codes from the spreadsheet in the iTunes App Store to 'purchase' the app you are distributing. Once you download the app and import it into Configurator, *go back to the VPP site and re-download the spreadsheet.* This spreadsheet will now have the word Redeemed in the cell where the download link used to be. Import only the *second* spreadsheet into Configurator.

Lastly, VPP Support is *sometimes* very forgiving with minor glitches like this and can get you back a license code, especially if the price of the app was substantial.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm pretty sure this is what I've done, that's how I was able to download the paid-for apps in iTunes and download the app for distribution.  I used a different account for purchasing than I do for downloading and redemption.   19/20 of the licenses are installed without issue. 1 license from each app will not deploy.

Comment: Emphasis on redownloading and reimporting the spreadsheet.